# How to map @OneToMany in ORM

Tags: hibernate, jpa

When there is a `@OneToMany` relationship the owner entity will have a `List` or a `Set` of the child element.

If I use `mappedBy` attribute the child element will have a member of type object of his parent. The thing is if I want to add a new child to the parent List/Set I always have to add the whole object , even in database of course there is only the Foreign Key. So I just want a confirmation that there is no other way to do this.

Comment: ORM = ***Object*** Relational Mapping framework.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you'd need to add an object to the collection. You can of course just fetch it via `em.find(id, MyClass.class)`.

If you really want to just insert the foreign key id into the DB, I suppose you could insert it into the DB using a native SQL query, but you'd have to refresh any loaded entities (since they'd be stale then). I don't suggest this strategy.

Comment: aha. Thanks. That is a good hint. A native query would reduce traffic in this case.